# svg responsive with background-size cover for image

Tags: html, css, svg

I've almost finished my background but it's not working properly, I'm trying to get the image to fit the viewbox dimensions. I need my image to responsive and to act like background-size:cover. I also need to have the scrollbars gone and I don't know why its there. Can someone help me get my image to fit the entire viewbox area and be responsive - I need it to be 100% width and 100% height and the image covered

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/YoevLP?editors=0100)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 490 500" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="hexagons" width="100%" height="100%">
      <g id="svg" fill="black" x="0" y="0"></g>    
    </pattern>
    <mask id="hexagon-halftone-mask">  
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#hexagons)" />
   </mask>
  </defs>

  <image id="svg-bg"  xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/07/11/37/tropical-1651426_960_720.jpg" mask="url(#hexagon-halftone-mask)"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/ouroborus/pen/RzQqRK I'm not making it an answer because I've forgotten exactly what changes I made and why but it should be the bare minimum to make it work. (At least in Chrome.) Comparing it to your own code might help you.

Comment: The most important change: removing width and height and adding `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`. You should add it as an answer!

Comment: There is no need to remove the `width` and `height`.  Their default values are `"100%"`. So removing them gives the exact same result as keeping them.